# read table after writing it in R

Tags: r, read.table

I used this command to write table in a file :

```
write.table(df,"file.txt",sep="\t",quote=F)
```

and it's something like this :

```
text    favorited   favoriteCount   replyToSN   created truncated   replyToSID  id  replyToUID  statusSource    screenName  retweetCount    isRetweet   retweeted   longitude   latitude
1   RT @MdM_France: #Présidentielle2017 STOP aux idées reçues sur l'aide médicale pour les étrangers (#AME) ! @FrancoisFillon Vivez-vous #DansL…    FALSE   0   NA  2017-03-02 13:45:34 FALSE   NA  837297834185601025  NA  <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/download/ipad" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPad</a>   MdM_NPdC    41  TRUE    FALSE   NA  NA
2   Ne devrions pas réfléchir à condamner @BFMTV ? Tant d'images violentes du djihad de @MLP_officiel, ça fait frémir. #Presidentielle2017  FALSE   0   NA  2017-03-02 13:45:32 FALSE   NA  837297827592224768  NA  <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>  RichardMolard   0   FALSE   FALSE   NA  NA
3   Il serait intéressant de faire un dépistage pour chaque candidat à la #Presidentielle2017 genre pour la cocaïne par exemple...  FALSE   0   NA  2017-03-02 13:45:29 FALSE   NA  837297813440561152  NA  <a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>  Samsa_Asmas 0   FALSE   FALSE   NA  NA
4   RT @Clovis1915: #Presidentielle2017 Certains veulent remplacer #Fillon par #Juppé ! Mais à quoi bon remplacer un futur condamné par un anci…    FALSE   0   NA  2017-03-02 13:45:26 FALSE   NA  837297802220879872  NA  <a href="http://twitter.com/download/android" rel="nofollow">Twitter for Android</a>    sireude1964 4   TRUE    FALSE   NA  NA
```

now whenever i try to read it again it gets a weird format and i find more rows than i should

what is the appropriate way to read it?

EDIT :

here's the command that i tried :

```
df <- read.table(file.choose(),header = TRUE , fill = TRUE ,  sep = "\t", quote="")
```

It didn't work tho, i tried changing the parameters as well and nothing

writing the table wasn't done by me, i just got the file and the command that wrote it

Comment: Maybe you want `write.table(..., row.names = FALSE)`? And when you are reading it, did you specify `\t` as the separator?

Comment: here's what i used  `df <- read.table(file.choose(),header = TRUE , fill = TRUE ,  sep = "\t", quote="")`

Comment: plus the file is already written and that's what they used.. i just got the file m not writing it